# Invalid byte sequence for encoding utf8 postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, encoding

When I try to do the following in the PSQL windows command shell:

```
 INSERT INTO NAMES (surname) VALUES ('børre')
```

I get the following:

```
 ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x9b
```

Show client_encoding and show server_encoding gives "utf8".

Why cant the server utf8 encoding handle ø ? I've tried to change the client_encoding to latin1, which solves the problem in the terminal, but if I insert via python or other, the character isn't saved as utf8.

Comment: SET client_encoding= 1252; GIYF

Comment: Or better, put your Windows console in unicode mode (see the psql manual) and use unicode for all Python strings.